# Создание 3д ифрейма

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, svg, three.js

Вопрос такой, стоит задача сделать `3d` интерфейс вот с такими окнами:

[image]

Использовал всё, что мог и знал:

**css 3d**:
возможная нагрузка: `css` > `svg`, `css` < `canvas`, `css` < `three.js`

- интерактивность
- возможность сделать `<iframe>`

- невозможность сделать 1 `<iframe>` на несколько элементов,  чтобы сделать данную геометрию в `3d` (по крайней мере не нашел)

**svg**:
допустимая нагрузка: svg < *

- интерактивность

- невозможность сделать `<iframe>` (`foreignObject` не брать, поскольку я не смог придать ему нужный объем чтобы было как в `3d`)

**canvas**:
возможная нагрузка: `canvas` > `svg`, `canvas` > `css`, `canvas` < `three.js`

- нет итеративности
- невозможность сделать `<iframe>` (именно, чтобы было пользоваться)

- (думаю если постараться, то можно было бы сделать похожий эффект, но тут все рухнуло из-за итеративности)

**three.js**:
допустимая нагрузка: `three.js` > *

- итеративность
- удобство при создании геометрии
- возможность пользоваться `canvas`

- невозможность сделать `<iframe>` (поскольку `<iframe>` вышел бы текстурой, то итеративность становится как у canvas)

Может, найдутся еще варианты, что можно попробовать?
Есть еще не плохая статейка об этих библиотеках, но вряд ли они решат мою задачу https://habrahabr.ru/post/140286/

Если пытаться делать на том? Что перечислил то в:
`canvas` и `three.js` нужно как-то в `<iframe>` сделать псевдо курсор? Который движется от положения точки в картинке.

В css 3d разделить `<iframe>` на части, чтобы отобразить на блоках, которые будут строить геометрию + должна быть синхронизация между кусочками чтобы выглядело  как 1.
А `svg` наверно вообще, надо как-то вывернуться на изнанку, чтобы сделать.

Comment: "невозможность сделать ифрейм" - не понял, что тут подразумевается.

Comment: @Qwertiy нужна по сути 3д модель с наложенной текстурой которая работает как обычный тег ифрейм с которой можно взаимодействовать только на геометрии и желательно с возможностью создания большого количества хотяб около 20

Comment: @Qwertiy а как узнать кто добавил вопрос в избранное и повышает важность вопроса мне просто интересно)

Comment: создаете айфрайм, рисуете его в текстуру, накладываете куда хотите, но начинаем слушать события перемещения курсора. А дальше остается события воспроизводить на айфрейме и снова его рисовать в текстуру. И так по кругу.

Comment: @OlmerDale в том то и вопрос я не знаю как такое реализовать но это решение мне действительно кажется реализуемым просто не знаю насколько точно можно воспроизводить и как коректировать позиции буду раз если подробнее опишите вот как мне определять в каком месте этот крестик на айфрайме если я его наложу как текстуру https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_raycast_texture

Comment: К чему такие сложности? Есть `THREE.CSS3DRenderer()` и пример использования в нем iframe'ов [https://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_youtube](https://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_youtube)

Comment: @prisoner849 я не могу наложить ифрейм на какую то геометрию и чтобы тот работал как на примере. нужна интерактивная текстура которая накладывается на геометрию. скриншот из айфрайме сделать то я смогу,но он тогда не реагирует. OlmerDale все правильно сказал,но проблема в том что я не знаю как воспроизводить события на айфрайме,как получить позицию курсора на текстуре я знаю,как от рисовать тоже,но как с симулировать  действия на айфрайме ума не приложу .
https://cdn.shazoo.ru/69302_xJcLpm6lHX_5monitors.png
только предположим что монитор это полигон модели  .

Comment: @prisoner849 Эх как же плохо я объясняю это ужс просто ... Любая геометрия(куб ,шар ,персонаж главное чтоб uv была) нажимая на текстуру на геометрии вычисляется позиция и передается на айфрейм и как то реагирует

Comment: [https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_raycast_texture](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_raycast_texture) - отличный пример. Зная UV координату курсора на текстуре можно вычислить ее положение на реальном iframe и [симулировать щелчок](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3277369/4045502)

Comment: @prisoner849 оформите пожалуйста свой комментарий как ответ

Comment: Создай несколько таких iframe потом с помощью CSS, задать для них стили в 3д, вот и всё.

Comment: Лучшее для 3д это openGL, будет все правдоподобно и реакция пользователя отрабатывается. Но iframe - увы!

Answer (score 1):

Если кто-то, как и я, наткнется на этот вопрос, то вот такое решение можно попробовать.

Реализация с использованием `CSS3DObject` и `CSS3DRenderer` из библиотеки `three.js`.

Выглядит итог вот так:
[image: Preview]

**Здесь оставлю код для сохранности**, он не запускается из сниппетов. [Поиграть с кодом можно на jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwfv18qe/)

---

```js
console.log(1);

import * as THREE from 'three';

import {TrackballControls} from 'TrackballControls';
import {CSS3DObject, CSS3DRenderer} from 'CSS3DRenderer';

let camera, scene, renderer;
let controls;


const urls = [
    'https://ru.wikipedia.org/',
    'https://wikipedia.org/',
    'https://rame0.ru/',
    'https://threejs.org/',
    'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q7AOvWpIVHU?rel=0',
    'https://google.com/',
    'https://vk.com',
];

function addUrlToIframe(url, div) {
    if (!url) {
        return
    }
    const iframe = div.querySelector('iframe');
    if (iframe === null) throw new Error("iframe is null");
    iframe.src = url;
}

function init() {
console.log('init')
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    if (container === undefined || container === null) throw new Error("container is undefined");

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
    camera.position.set(0, 400, 1500);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    renderer = new CSS3DRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


    const group = new THREE.Group();

    const stage = document.getElementById('stage');
    if (stage === undefined || stage === null) throw new Error("stage is undefined");
    const rows = document.getElementsByClassName('rows');
    if (rows === undefined || rows === null) throw new Error("rows is undefined");
    const url_rows = Math.ceil(urls.length / 5);
    if (url_rows > rows.length) {
        const new_row = rows[0].cloneNode(true);
        stage.appendChild(new_row);
    }

    const screen_cols = document.getElementsByClassName('col');
    for (let i = 0; i < screen_cols.length && urls[i]; i++) {
        addUrlToIframe(urls[i], screen_cols[i]);
    }

    group.add(new CSS3DObject(document.getElementById("stage")))
    scene.add(group);

    controls = new TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.rotateSpeed = 4;


    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

    // Block iframe events when dragging camera
    const blocker = document.getElementById('blocker');
    if (blocker === undefined || blocker === null) throw new Error("blocker is undefined");
    blocker.style.display = 'none';

    controls.addEventListener('start', function () {

        blocker.style.display = '';

    });
    controls.addEventListener('end', function () {

        blocker.style.display = 'none';

    });

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}



init();
animate();
```

```css
:root{
    --width: 1200px;
    --z-translate: -2250px;
}

body {
    background-color: #555;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 225px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 225px;
    perspective: 800px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 225px;
}

#stage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.rows {
    position: relative;
    top: 160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 600px;
    width: var(--width);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-0px);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-0px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: translateZ(-0px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.col {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 600px;
    width: var(--width);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Times, serif;
    font-size: 124pt;
    color: black;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.screen{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.screen1  {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
    -moz-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
    transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
}

.screen2 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
    -moz-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
    transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
}

.screen3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
}

.screen4 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
    -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
    transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
}

.screen5 {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
    -moz-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
    transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(var(--z-translate));
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="stage">
        <div class="rows">
            <div class="col screen1">
                <iframe class="screen" src=""
                        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="col screen2">
                <iframe class="screen" src=""
                        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="col screen3">
                <iframe class="screen" src=""
                        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="col screen4">
                <iframe class="screen" src=""
                        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="col screen5">
                <iframe class="screen" src=""
                        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="blocker"></div>


<script type="importmap">
{
"imports": 
  {
    "three": "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js",
    "TrackballControls": "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js",
    "CSS3DRenderer": "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"
  }
}




</script>
```